# What are the differences between the console version and PC release?

Tags: version-differences, xcom-enemy-unknown

[This article](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/09/07/xcom-enemy-unknown-pc-features-revealed-prettier-and-more-tactical-than-on-consoles/) on PC Gamers' website contains an interview with the lead designer for XCOM: Enemy Unknown, who speaks about there being differences such as higher resolution textures and a new user interface which displays *"loads more data and allowing for a speed of interaction that changes how players approach tactical decisions"* being available on the PC version in comparison to consoles.

Are there any other differences between the PC and console versions known at the moment, or any differences between individual console releases of the game?

Comment: It sounds like there is a pretty clear graphical difference.

Comment: PC version also gets the tactical view grid and other things like that, but as mentioned there won't be a definitive list (and thus the question can't be fully answered) until closer to/after the release date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is still no definitive list, but there's a pretty comprehensive review [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NS4NCmhwrLw).

According to this guy,

- PC has better textures and allows to zoom in closer,
- PC loads faster,
- when playing with a mouse you have minor conveniences like hovering on top of aliens-in-view icons to see hit percentages (I'm playing with a mouse and I've never knew it).
- **Important:** multiplayer is not cross-platform, so you better follow your friends.

Reviewer explicitly states that he felt no tactical performance gain on any platform.

Tactical view grid should also be classified as a minor convenience - after some hours, you'll be easily telling distances at a glance.